# How do I define mapping in solidity where each value is array of Struct?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle

I'm trying to define a mapping, where each value should be an array of struct. Not sure, if this is possible? If yes then what wrong I'm doing here?

After defining, I also need to push values to the array as shown below. Please advise if it is correct.

```
struct Review {
    uint rating;
    address reviewer;
    string description;
    uint dateAdded;
}


mapping (uint => Review[]) public ratings;

function rateBook(uint id, uint rating, string comments) onlyMember {
    if (id > numBooks || rating < 1 || rating > 5) {
        throw;
    }

    ratings[id].push(Review({
        rating: rating,
        reviewer: msg.sender,
        description: comments,
        dateAdded: now
        }));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is correct, here's my test code:

```
import "dapple/test.sol";

contract MappingArrayOfStructs is Test {

  struct Review {
    uint rating;
    address reviewer;
    string description;
    uint dateAdded;
  }

  mapping (uint => Review[]) ratings;

  function testMappingArrayOfStructs() {
    //@log push to ratings array
    ratings[0].push(Review({
      rating: 0,
      reviewer: msg.sender,
      description: "",
      dateAdded: now
    }));
    //@log `uint ratings[0][0].dateAdded`
  }

}
```

This can be run with `dapple test --report` and produces the following report:

```
MappingArrayOfStructs
  test mapping array of structs
  LOG:  push to ratings array
  LOG:  1493284381
  Passed!
```

When you make a state variable public, the compiler automatically generates a getter function as described in the documentation https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#getter-functions:

```
function ratings(uint arg1, uint arg2) returns (uint rating, address reviewer, string description, uint dateAdded) {
    rating = ratings[arg1][arg2].rating;
    reviewer = ratings[arg1][arg2].reviewer;
    description = ratings[arg1][arg2].description;
    dateAdded = ratings[arg1][arg2].dateAdded;
}
```

You can access the member data in Solidity like this: `var (rating, reviewer, description, dateAdded) = reviews.ratings(0, 0);`

If you are using Truffle then the generated bindings treat tuples as arrays, so you can access the member data in JS like this:

```
var Reviews = artifacts.require("./Reviews.sol");

contract('Reviews', function(accounts) {
  it("should return the correct book rating", function() {
    var reviews;
    return Reviews.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      reviews = instance;
      return reviews.rateBook(0, 5, "This book changed my life");
    }).then(function() {
      return reviews.ratings.call(0, 0);
    }).then(function(review) {
      assert.equal(review[0], 5, "5 wasn't the rating for the book with id 0");
    });
  });
});
```

Likewise, a Truffle themed test would work like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/Reviews.sol";

contract TestReviews {

  function testRateBookUsingDeployedContract() {
    Reviews reviews = Reviews(DeployedAddresses.Reviews());

    reviews.rateBook(0, 5, "Test comment");
    var (rating, reviewer, description, dateAdded) = reviews.ratings(0, 0);

    Assert.equal(rating, 5, "Book should have a rating of 5");
  }

}
```

On the command line you can simply run these tests using `truffle test` and you will get the following output:

```
Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/Reviews.sol...
Compiling ./test/TestReviews.sol...
Compiling truffle/Assert.sol...
Compiling truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol...


  TestReviews
    ✓ testRateBookUsingDeployedContract (38ms)

  Contract: Reviews
    ✓ should return the correct book rating (65ms)


  2 passing (198ms)
```

Comment: One more question on this, how do I access ratings outside of contract? I'm writing a test case in JS and this is how I was trying to but every time it is coming as undefined. 
// lms is the constructor of my contract
let rating = await lms.ratings[1][accounts[0]].rating; //code fails here itself
let description = await lms.ratings[1][accounts[0]].description;
console.log(rating, description);

Comment: I've updated the answer with the information.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for explaining this. You are the Man!